# Gwt 2.8-rc1 super dev mode is not working on IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.5

Tags: java, gwt, intellij-idea

My project is starting correctly with GWT 2.7 and 2.8-beta1 in super dev mode
Unfortunately since 2.8-rc1 release it is not starting.
Looks like GWT project dependencies are not configured correctly.
IDE: IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.5

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\bin\java" -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Djava.naming.factory.initial=org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.InitialContextFactory -Didea.launcher.port=7536 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\<REPO>\com\google\gwt\gwt-codeserver\2.8.0-rc1\gwt-codeserver-2.8.0-rc1.jar;C:\<REPO>\com\google\gwt\gwt-dev\2.8.0-rc1\gwt-dev-2.8.0-rc1.jar;xxx\xxx\src\main\java;xxx\xxx\src\main\resources;xxx\xxx\target\generated-sources\gwt;C:\<REPO>\com\google\jsinterop\jsinterop-annotations\1.0.0\jsinterop-annotations-1.0.0-sources.jar;xxx\domain-model\src\main\java;xxx\domain-model\src\main\resources;xxx\sso-security-lib\src\main\java;xxx\sso-security-lib\src\main\resources;xxx\seleniumtests\src\main\java;xxx\smartgwt-data-integration\src\main\java;xxx\generator\src\main\java;xxx\generator\src\main\resources;xxx\gwt-ui-utils\src\main\java;xxx\gwt-ui-utils\src\main\resources;xxx\gwt-ui-utils\target\generated-sources\gwt;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\rt.jar;c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\bcprov-ext-jdk15on-154.jar;c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\ext\bcprov-jdk15on-154.jar;xxx\xxx\target\test-classes;xxx\xxx\target\xxx\WEB-INF\classes;C:\<REPO>\org\springframework\spring-context\4.2.4.RELEASE\spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\springframework\spring-aop\4.2.4.RELEASE\spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\springframework\spring-beans\4.2.4.RELEASE\spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\springframework\spring-core\4.2.4.RELEASE\spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\springframework\spring-expression\4.2.4.RELEASE\spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\4.2.4.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\springframework\spring-web\4.2.4.RELEASE\spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\springframework\spring-aspects\4.2.4.RELEASE\spring-aspects-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.8.7\aspectjweaver-1.8.7.jar;C:\<REPO>\com\google\gwt\gwt-servlet\2.8.0-rc1\gwt-servlet-2.8.0-rc1.jar;C:\<REPO>\com\google\gwt\gwt-user\2.8.0-rc1\gwt-user-2.8.0-rc1.jar;C:\<REPO>\com\google\jsinterop\jsinterop-annotations\1.0.0\jsinterop-annotations-1.0.0.jar;C:\<REPO>\javax\servlet\javax.servlet-api\3.1.0\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\w3c\css\sac\1.3\sac-1.3.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-plus\8.1.19.v20160209\jetty-plus-8.1.19.v20160209.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\eclipse\jetty\orbit\javax.transaction\1.1.1.v201105210645\javax.transaction-1.1.1.v201105210645.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-webapp\8.1.19.v20160209\jetty-webapp-8.1.19.v20160209.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-xml\8.1.19.v20160209\jetty-xml-8.1.19.v20160209.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-util\8.1.19.v20160209\jetty-util-8.1.19.v20160209.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-servlet\8.1.19.v20160209\jetty-servlet-8.1.19.v20160209.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-security\8.1.19.v20160209\jetty-security-8.1.19.v20160209.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-jndi\8.1.19.v20160209\jetty-jndi-8.1.19.v20160209.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-server\8.1.19.v20160209\jetty-server-8.1.19.v20160209.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\eclipse\jetty\orbit\javax.servlet\3.0.0.v201112011016\javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-continuation\8.1.19.v20160209\jetty-continuation-8.1.19.v20160209.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-http\8.1.19.v20160209\jetty-http-8.1.19.v20160209.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-io\8.1.19.v20160209\jetty-io-8.1.19.v20160209.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\eclipse\jetty\orbit\javax.mail.glassfish\1.4.1.v201005082020\javax.mail.glassfish-1.4.1.v201005082020.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\eclipse\jetty\orbit\javax.activation\1.1.0.v201105071233\javax.activation-1.1.0.v201105071233.jar;C:\<REPO>\commons-dbcp\commons-dbcp\1.4\commons-dbcp-1.4.jar;C:\<REPO>\commons-pool\commons-pool\1.5.4\commons-pool-1.5.4.jar;C:\<REPO>\junit\junit\4.9\junit-4.9.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.1\hamcrest-core-1.1.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\mockito\mockito-all\1.9.5\mockito-all-1.9.5.jar;C:\<REPO>\javax\validation\validation-api\1.0.0.GA\validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar;C:\<REPO>\javax\validation\validation-api\1.0.0.GA\validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\4.0.3.RELEASE\spring-security-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\<REPO>\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\springframework\security\spring-security-config\4.0.3.RELEASE\spring-security-config-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\springframework\security\spring-security-web\4.0.3.RELEASE\spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\<REPO>\javax\servlet\jstl\1.2\jstl-1.2.jar;C:\<REPO>\com\xxx\commons\authentication\xxx-authentication\1.0.5\xxx-authentication-1.0.5.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\samba\jcifs\jcifs\1.3.12\jcifs-1.3.12.jar;C:\<REPO>\com\ioplex\jespa-licensed\1.1.13-INTERNAL-1\jespa-licensed-1.1.13-INTERNAL-1.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\springframework\security\spring-security-ldap\4.0.3.RELEASE\spring-security-ldap-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\springframework\spring-tx\4.2.2.RELEASE\spring-tx-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\springframework\ldap\spring-ldap-core\2.1.0.RELEASE\spring-ldap-core-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.12\slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar;C:\<REPO>\com\google\guava\guava-gwt\19.0\guava-gwt-19.0.jar;C:\<REPO>\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\1.3.9\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:\<REPO>\com\google\errorprone\error_prone_annotations\2.0.2\error_prone_annotations-2.0.2.jar;C:\<REPO>\com\google\j2objc\j2objc-annotations\0.1\j2objc-annotations-0.1.jar;C:\<REPO>\com\google\guava\guava\19.0\guava-19.0.jar;xxx\domain-model\target\classes;C:\<REPO>\com\googlecode\mvp4g\mvp4g\1.3.1\mvp4g-1.3.1.jar;C:\<REPO>\com\google\gwt\inject\gin\1.5.0\gin-1.5.0.jar;C:\<REPO>\com\google\inject\guice\3.0-rc2\guice-3.0-rc2.jar;C:\<REPO>\javax\inject\javax.inject\1\javax.inject-1.jar;C:\<REPO>\com\google\inject\extensions\guice-assistedinject\3.0-rc2\guice-assistedinject-3.0-rc2.jar;xxx\sso-security-lib\target\classes;C:\<REPO>\org\springframework\security\spring-security-taglibs\4.0.3.RELEASE\spring-security-taglibs-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\springframework\security\spring-security-acl\4.0.3.RELEASE\spring-security-acl-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\<REPO>\oracle\ojdbc14\10.2.0.4.0\ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\springframework\spring-test\4.2.4.RELEASE\spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar;xxx\seleniumtests\target\classes;xxx\smartgwt-data-integration\target\classes;C:\<REPO>\com\smartgwt\smartgwt\6.0p\smartgwt-6.0p.jar;C:\<REPO>\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.5\commons-lang-2.5.jar;C:\<REPO>\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.1\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;C:\<REPO>\net\sourceforge\collections\collections-generic\4.01\collections-generic-4.01.jar;C:\<REPO>\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils\1.8.0\commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar;C:\<REPO>\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.1\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\hibernate\hibernate-commons-annotations\3.2.0.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\3.6.0.Final\hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar;C:\<REPO>\antlr\antlr\2.7.6\antlr-2.7.6.jar;C:\<REPO>\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\<REPO>\javax\transaction\jta\1.1\jta-1.1.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\hibernate\hibernate-ehcache\3.6.1.Final\hibernate-ehcache-3.6.1.Final.jar;C:\<REPO>\net\sf\ehcache\ehcache\1.5.0\ehcache-1.5.0.jar;C:\<REPO>\backport-util-concurrent\backport-util-concurrent\3.1\backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar;C:\<REPO>\net\sf\jsr107cache\jsr107cache\1.0\jsr107cache-1.0.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\hibernate\hibernate-entitymanager\3.6.0.Final\hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.0.Final.jar;C:\<REPO>\javassist\javassist\3.12.0.GA\javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\hibernate\javax\persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api\1.0.0.Final\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\hibernate\hibernate-validator\4.1.0.Final\hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-core-asl\1.8.0\jackson-core-asl-1.8.0.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-mapper-asl\1.8.0\jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.0.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\springframework\spring-orm\4.2.4.RELEASE\spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\4.2.4.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\slf4j\slf4j-log4j12\1.6.1\slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar;C:\<REPO>\log4j\log4j\1.2.16\log4j-1.2.16.jar;C:\<REPO>\log4j\apache-log4j-extras\1.2.17\apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar;C:\<REPO>\cglib\cglib-nodep\2.2\cglib-nodep-2.2.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\hsqldb\hsqldb\2.3.2\hsqldb-2.3.2.jar;C:\<REPO>\com\thoughtworks\xstream\xstream\1.4.3\xstream-1.4.3.jar;C:\<REPO>\xmlpull\xmlpull\1.1.3.1\xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar;C:\<REPO>\xpp3\xpp3_min\1.1.4c\xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar;xxx\generator\target\classes;C:\<REPO>\org\aspectj\aspectjrt\1.6.12\aspectjrt-1.6.12.jar;C:\<REPO>\com\informatica\powercenter\sdk\jmf\9.1.0\jmf-9.1.0.jar;C:\<REPO>\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\1.0.6\jaxb-impl-1.0.6.jar;C:\<REPO>\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\1.0\jaxb-api-1.0.jar;C:\<REPO>\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-libs\1.0.6\jaxb-libs-1.0.6.jar;C:\<REPO>\com\sun\msv\datatype\xsd\xsdlib\20060615\xsdlib-20060615.jar;C:\<REPO>\isorelax\isorelax\20030108\isorelax-20030108.jar;C:\<REPO>\relaxngDatatype\relaxngDatatype\20020414\relaxngDatatype-20020414.jar;C:\<REPO>\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-xjc\1.0.6\jaxb-xjc-1.0.6.jar;C:\<REPO>\com\informatica\powercenter\sdk\jmf-jaxb\9.1.0\jmf-jaxb-9.1.0.jar;C:\<REPO>\com\informatica\powercenter\sdk\pmserversdk\9.1.0\pmserversdk-9.1.0.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\apache\poi\poi\3.9\poi-3.9.jar;C:\<REPO>\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.5\commons-codec-1.5.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\apache\poi\poi-contrib\3.1-FINAL\poi-contrib-3.1-FINAL.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\apache\poi\poi-ooxml\3.9\poi-ooxml-3.9.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\apache\poi\poi-ooxml-schemas\3.9\poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\apache\xmlbeans\xmlbeans\2.3.0\xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar;C:\<REPO>\stax\stax-api\1.0.1\stax-api-1.0.1.jar;C:\<REPO>\net\sf\saxon\saxon-dom\8.7\saxon-dom-8.7.jar;xxx\gwt-ui-utils\target\classes;C:\<REPO>\net\customware\gwt\dispatch\gwt-dispatch\1.2.0\gwt-dispatch-1.2.0.jar;C:\<REPO>\net\sf\saxon\saxon\8.7\saxon-8.7.jar;C:\<REPO>\commons-fileupload\commons-fileupload\1.2.2\commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar;C:\<REPO>\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\<REPO>\javax\validation\validation-api\1.1.0.Final\validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\ow2\asm\asm\5.0.3\asm-5.0.3.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\ow2\asm\asm-util\5.0.3\asm-util-5.0.3.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\ow2\asm\asm-commons\5.0.3\asm-commons-5.0.3.jar;C:\<REPO>\org\ow2\asm\asm-tree\5.0.3\asm-tree-5.0.3.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.4\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode -superDevMode -war C:\Users\xxx\.IntelliJIdea2016.2\system\gwt\jboss6.4-migration-xxx.b5723cb3\xxx.1652beb5\run\www -remoteUI 7907:IntelliJIdea -startupUrl core.html com.xxx.xxx.workflowdetails.WorkflowDetails com.xxx.xxx.migration.Migration com.xxx.xxx.useroptions.UserOptions com.xxx.xxx.sessiondetails.SessionDetails com.xxx.xxx.validationdetails.ValidationDetails com.xxx.xxx.builddetails.BuildDetails com.xxx.xxx.core com.xxx.xxx.dependencymgmt.DependencyMgmt com.xxx.xxx.generator.Generator
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cern/colt/map/OpenIntObjectHashMap
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.collect.IntMultimap.<init>(IntMultimap.java:28)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.StringAnalyzableTypeEnvironment.<init>(StringAnalyzableTypeEnvironment.java:68)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.MinimalRebuildCache.<init>(MinimalRebuildCache.java:192)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompilerContext$Builder.<init>(CompilerContext.java:37)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.<init>(DevModeBase.java:636)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.<init>(DevMode.java:457)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:424)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cern.colt.map.OpenIntObjectHashMap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 12 more
```

When I add missing dependency to my project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>colt</groupId>
    <artifactId>colt</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm getting different problem related with wrong jetty-server version (I have depoendencies to 8.1.19.v20160209 but looks like 9.x should be used):

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/HttpConfiguration$Customizer
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode$ArgHandlerServer.setString(DevMode.java:179)
    at com.google.gwt.util.tools.ArgHandlerString.handle(ArgHandlerString.java:26)
    at com.google.gwt.util.tools.ToolBase.processArgs(ToolBase.java:291)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.ArgProcessorBase.processArgs(ArgProcessorBase.java:30)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:425)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Let me know if you have similar problems with latest GWT releases. I could try to guess versions of all dependencies that should be used but it is not a good apreach. This should be pre-configured.

UPDATE:

When I generate simple GWT project:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo -DarchetypeArtifactId=gwt-maven-plugin -DarchetypeVersion=2.8.0-rc3
```

and import it to Intelij then dependencies are correct. I have the same gwt-maven-plugin version. I re-generated project in IDE. What I'm missing ?

Comment: Same problem for me, with GWT 2.8 (Release).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add this dependency to your pom.xml file : [gwt-dev](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gwt/gwt-dev/2.8.0) 
(gwt-dev has all the dependencies needed)

If you create a new GWT 2.8.0 module, you can check that, that contains gwt-dev dependency in the pom file.

Comment: Thanks! Now it is starting however I still have some old version of jetty in the dependencies, but I think I will be able to locate it.

Comment: If you add this dependency then classic DevMode won't work. With scope = compile there will be 503 error in browser. With scope = test code-server will fail with message "Error: could not find or load main class com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode" on debugger attachment.