# Object of class 'com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.WebAppContextWithReload' is not of type 'org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext'

Tags: java, maven, gwt, intellij-idea, jetty

When I'm trying to start my GWT project in SuperDevMode in Intellij I'm getting following error:

```
    2016-11-22 09:32:25,752 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-9.2.14.v20151106
Starting Jetty on port 8888
   [WARN] Failed startup of context c.g.g.d.s.j.WebAppContextWithReload@6e96259d{/,file:/C:/Users/xxx/.IntelliJIdea2016.2/system/gwt/xxxTrunk.1eba6fcd/xxx.b010468/run/www/,STARTING}{C:\Users\xxx\.IntelliJIdea2016.2\system\gwt\xxxTrunk.1eba6fcd\xxx.b010468\run\www}
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object of class 'com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.WebAppContextWithReload' is not of type 'org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext'. Object Class and type Class are from different loaders. in file:/C:/Users/xxx/.IntelliJIdea2016.2/system/gwt/xxxTrunk.1eba6fcd/xxx.b010468/run/www/WEB-INF/jetty-web.xml
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:296)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration.configure(JettyWebXmlConfiguration.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1337)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
```

Maven configuration:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

...

<!-- Additional GWT libraries -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.customware.gwt.dispatch</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-dispatch</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.mvp4g</groupId>
    <artifactId>mvp4g</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.smartgwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>smartgwt</artifactId>
    <version>6.0p</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava-gwt</artifactId>
    <version>19.0</version>
</dependency>

...

<plugins>
<!-- GWT Maven Plugin -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>test</goal>
                    <goal>i18n</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>

    <configuration>
        <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx1024m -Xms512m -Xss512k</extraJvmArgs>
        <runTarget>xxx.html</runTarget>
        <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>
        <i18nMessagesBundle>xxx.Messages</i18nMessagesBundle>
        <style>OBF</style>
        <disableCastChecking>true</disableCastChecking>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I added gwt-dev as suggested in:
[Gwt 2.8-rc1 super dev mode is not working on IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40149981/gwt-2-8-rc1-super-dev-mode-is-not-working-on-intellij-idea-2016-2-5)

Run configuration VM option:

-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Djava.naming.factory.initial=org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.InitialContextFactory

jetty-web.xml configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">
<Configure id="wac" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <New id="configurationDataSource" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">

        <Arg>jdbc/configurationDataSource</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <New class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
                <Set name="driverClassName">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</Set>
                <Set name="url">xxx</Set>
                <Set name="username">xxx</Set>
                <Set name="password">xxx/Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </New>
    <New id="configuration" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.EnvEntry">
        <Arg>configuration</Arg>
        <Arg type="java.lang.String">classpath:META-INF/application-local.properties</Arg>
        <Arg type="boolean">true</Arg>
    </New>
</Configure>
```

I analyzed mvn dependency:tree. There is no additional jetty version included

Path to GWT installation directory:

C:\Users\xxx.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-dev\2.8.0

JDK version: 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem disappeared when I updated IntelliJ IDEA from 2016.2.5 to 2016.3